# What is a good usage of the is-operator

Tags: c#

What is a *good* usage of the is-operator?

The construct below for casting is not the recommended way to go, virtually all documentation prefers the as-operator with a null-check.

```
if(obj is SomeClass)
{
  SomeClass some = (SomeClass)obj;
  ....
}
```

And sure this is a (very small) performance increase and some even mention the tread safety.
And yes this is true...

So, why do we have the is-operator?
Where does the "as-operator with a null-check" not work or is not the way to go?
Does is have an advantage to restrict the scope of you declaration you get by using the is-operator?

Comment: I think a situation is that when you want to test the type of something, but doesn't need to assign it to a variable and use it?

Comment: [Is is as or is as is?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/16/is-is-as-or-is-as-is.aspx)

Comment: @Zev: That sounds as if Eric has  had a drop too much: _"de jure is is is, and as is as is is, but de facto is is as and as is isinst"_ :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`as` doesn't work with non-nullable `struct`s:

```
object o = 123;
int i = o as int; // compile error
```

however:

```
object o = 123;
if(o is int) {
    int i = (int)o;
    //...
}
```

of course, from 2.0 onwards you could also use:

```
int? i = o as int?;
```

and test for `null` like usual.

There is *also* the scenario that you don't care about the values of the object... you just need to know what it is:

```
if(obj is Something)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Seriously, don't do that");
// phew! dodged a bullet; we're ok here...
```

Note that `GetType()` is not appropriate for this, as you don't want to have to consider subclasses, interfaces, etc manually.

Comment: This link is worth reading  in this regard http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/08/what-s-the-difference-between-as-and-cast-operators.aspx

Comment: @Tim good spot, but while that is *true*, it doesn't affect the difference between `is` and `as`. That affects `as` vs *cast*.